# htaccess subdomain silent redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have subdomains for each user, user1.domain.com that successfully points to domain.com/user1.

My question is how do I do it so that http://user1.domain.com/admin does a SILENT redirect to http://domain.com/admin?

I want to apply this to all subdirectories in the subdomain, so user1.domain.com/cart silent redirects to domain.com/cart & user1.domain.com/cart/checkout/confirmation -> domain.com/cart/checkout/confirmation so on and so forth. Bear in mind that this directories don't actually exist in the subdomains, only the root domain.

I've tried searching Stackoverflow but could not find an answer to my specific issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a redirect unless the browser knows about it, there's no such thing as a "silent" redirect. You have 2 options, you can either proxy on behalf of the browser, or you can internally rewrite the request **if both `user1.domain.com` and `domain.com` share the same document root**.

To proxy:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [L,P]
```

The `P` flag indicates a proxy. This rule *will not* work unless you have mod_proxy loaded. If all your domains point to the same document root, then you can simply rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The 2nd option worked just fine. A note for anyone looking at this in the future: Do not actually create folders for these subdomains. Just parse the url and reference your db based on the subdomain.