# Redirecting subdomain to index.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

How do I rewrite all subdomain of a domain to the index page of that domain along with url parameter.
Basically xxx.domain.com should redirect to domain.com/index.php?subdomain=xxx and keeping the original url (xxx.domain.com) in the address bar(rewrite in the background). Please note that the subdomain xxx does not exist (not created).

My question is somewhat similar to [htaccess subdomain silent redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814110/htaccess-subdomain-silent-redirect) so I tried that but I get "Can’t connect to the server" error from the browser.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Are both subdomain and main domain pointing to same site root directory?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: I have now added that to my post. Thanks

Comment: Please note that the subdomain xxx does not exist (not created)

Comment: subdomain has be be crated first in inside `VirtualHost` section of Apache config